# Magento 2: Configure just only for one country

Tags: magento2, php, layout, frontend

We have a magento 2 store, with more than 20 stores location and they are being separately maintained in the same web site, we do sell only in the country. is there anyway that I could completely get rid of those events where they pop up at certain occasions asking to select country, since we operate only in the country I want to get omitted(hide would be better) each and every event where a customer is being questioned asking for the country.

Comment: As per default magento flow there is no popup where user needs to select country. Country is only needed for shipping and billing information.

Comment: Does it sound like , it pops up ?Nop, what I meant was country selecting field shouldn't be appearing where they're now at.

Comment: Let me appreciate the question first (: Magento provides tons of technical facilities and sometimes we don't need all of them so when we need need only one language or one country or even when we don't need some type of product. Let's say downloadable product. - if we disable all the stuff what we don't need in near future. The output will be very different and fast. And near to perfection.

Answer (score 0):

General -> Country Options -> Allow Countries (for sales)

Instead to have a default country (Brazil) in cart shipping quotes you have to set it in

Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods -> (Shipping Module) -> Ship to Applicable Countries [YES]

In Ship to Specific Countries you select the countrys.